# Example of a non singular square matrix such that $A+A^{-1} = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there any example of a non singular square matrix $A$ such that $A+A^{-1} = 0$? Are they any specific type of matrices or can these be found under any category of matrices (such as symmetric, hermitian, unitary etc.)?

Thanks...

Comment: Multiply with $A$ to obtain the 'simpler' equation: $A^2 = -I$. A simple example is $A = iI$ and $A=-iI$. In general the matrix $A$ can only have $\pm i$ as its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Winther: Thanks... Are $A^{-2}=-I$ categorized into any special type of matrices?

Comment: All we can say (I think) is that the eigenvalues as $\pm i$ and the determinent therefore has unit length. It is not hermitian as it has imaginary eigenvalues and it does not have to be symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Aaron That may not exist. I am sure $1$ and $-1$ do exist.